# Framework for implementing paywall for macOS apps outside App Store

Tags: macos, cocoa

I plan to distribute a macOS app both inside and outside Mac App Store. For the non App Store version, is there any popular framework for implementing paywall? Basic features in the app will be free and a paid license is only required for unlocking certain advanced features.